# How to calculate the Position Weight Matrix score?

Tags: bioinformatics

Can anyone explain me how to calculate the Position Weight Matrix score?

I know the formula, but I don't understand it. I have a table with the frequences of nucleotides, and a table with the PWM scores:

Frequences of nucleotides:

```
Position:            1       2        3        4        5

A                    0       0.9      0.1      0.6      0.2
C                    0       0        0.2      0.1      0.2
G                    0       0        0.1      0        0.1
T                    1       0.1      0.6      0.3      0.5
```

And I have the corresponding PWM scores:

```
Position:            1       2        3        4         5

A                            1.848   -1.322    1.263    -0.322
C                                    -0.322   -1.322    -0.322
G                                    -1.322             -1.322
T                    1      -1.322    1.263    0.263     1
```

But, I have no idea how this scores are calculated.
The formula is:

[image]

But I don't understand this.

Can anyone explain me step by step how I can calculate this scores?

I especially don't understand how to calculate `p(b,i)`.

Thanks! :)

Comment: `p(b,i)` comes from the frequency of the nucleotide `b` at position `i` divided by the number of sequences you have taken for considering the score. This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_weight_matrix) page explains all need to know.